# Do the different branches of the Brotherhood of Steel ever come into contact?

Tags: video-games, fallout

In the intro of Fallout:Brotherhood of Steel it states that there was a disagreement in the brotherhood and that the minority lost and were sent East to investigate.
This effectively cut the BOS into 2 different branches. 
I remember that in Fallout 3 the BOS is in the Washington DC area and they don't tolerate mutants/deathclaws.

Is there any canon/fiction that states what happens when the Chicago BOS comes into contact with Washington DC (original) BOS?

Also, is the Washington DC branch the "original" branch or is there another one?

Comment: How would anyone know what would happen? This question seems to invite speculation more than facts. You might want to rephrase that question along the line of "Is there any information on the relationship of the two branches".

Comment: The original Brotherhood of Steel is from California, the Washington branch is a liberal off-shoot

Comment: So if the original is from California is the one in Fallout :BOS actually the offspring that gets stranded in Chicago and keeps going towards Washington or is this not cannon? Kind of confused a bit here.

Comment: The original BOS did originate in the far west US, in the original Fallout game.  There is certainly some amount of canon information available throughout the various franchise titles that details the origins and some differences between the various BOS factions.

Comment: Don't forget about the Outcasts. AFAIK they never do meet, so no.

Comment: im sure theres fan fiction somewhere.

Comment: Also FYI, `Fallout: Brotherhood of Steel` is not canon. The Midwest/Eastern BOS seems to be only a part of Fallout: BOS and Fallout Tactics games, which have been removed from canon. There's a lot of detail on it here: https://fallout.gamepedia.com/Eastern_Brotherhood_of_Steel (spoiler warning)

Comment: Gotcha... Chicago (Fallout Tactics) branch is retconed out of existance. so now there is only Cali branches and the DC branch.

Answer (score 1):

The Brotherhood of Steel originally developed in California, with a second contingent based in Appalachia (West Virginia). This second group was in contact with the first until communication systems broke down, and the Appalachia group was wiped out not long after this.

The Brotherhood later expanded from their California location, with well-known chapters located around Vegas, Washington DC, and Boston. There are additional references to locations such as [Montana](https://fallout-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Montana_bunker), with non-canon locations in Texas, Chicago, and Colorado. Other canon and non-canon groups are referenced vaguely at times (usually without naming locations); some are splinter groups, while others are expeditions that don't permanently settle in one spot or are wiped out.

In the non-canon Chicago chapter, they expand and grow to control a large Midwest area, but are eventually reduced to a small group after a number of wars and further problems. They have contact with other Brotherhood groups, but the details of those contacts are not well known, beyond that the main group and the Chicago group do not see eye to eye.

In canon, there is still a Chicago group that arrived by airship and were forced to fight against super mutants. Conversations in Fallout 4 are unclear about the status of this group; they are known to have existed and are considered rogue members of the order, which necessitates some form of contact taking place. But other mentions of them seem to indicate this group was wiped out. See footnotes 6-9 [here](https://fallout-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Eastern_Brotherhood_of_Steel) for the direct quotes.

To my knowledge, no real interaction between Chicago and any other BoS group has been well documented/discussed/shown in any Fallout media, canon or otherwise, other than obscure or partial references. We know they had interactions of some sort, both in canon and not-canon, but the details are left to speculation.